# How to manually solve a recursive function returning another recursive function?

Tags: recursion

This is a sample function which returns x<sup>y</sup>

```
int fun(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)   return 0;
    return (x + fun(x, y-1));
}

int fun2(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    return fun(a, fun2(a, b-1));
}
```

> How does fun2(2,3) return x<sup>y</sup>?

How would be they put on stack for execution?
If asked to solve this manually, how would be the algorithm broken down?

Comment: Think of it as a nested `for` loop.

Comment: None of your function return a recursive function. Before call to `fun` can be made in `fun2` the answer from `fun2(a, b-1)` needs to be calculated. That happens (stack grows) until you hit base case. Result i `1`, you then apply `fun` with `a` and 1 and follow that recursion until it returns and then you have another answer to a `fun2(a, b-1)` so you continue down until the very first call.

Answer (score 0):

your `fun` function will return `x*y` for instance if you call function fun with x and x it will give you x<sup>2</sup>.

consider that for finding x<sup>y</sup> with function fun, you just need to call fun like fun(x,x<sup>y-1</sup>), so if your this `fun2(a,0)` generate a<sup>0</sup> = 1 this `fun(a, fun2(a, 0))` will return a<sup>1</sup> but `fun(a, fun2(a, 0))` is return value of `fun2(a,1)`, so fun(a,1) = a<sup>1</sup> with this approach you have fun2(a, b-1) = a<sup>b-1</sup> and as I said above you have fun(a, fun2(a,b-1)) = a<sup>b</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start solving the fun(int x, int y) function because it doesn't call any other functions, but itself

Let's analyse the x variable on example `$result = fun(x, y);`

```
$result = 
x + ( // fun(x, y - 1)      
    x + ( // fun(x, y - 2)  
        .......
                x + ( // fun(x, 1)
                    x + 0 // fun(x, 0) is 0
                )
        .......
    )
);
```

Note that this is `x + (x + ( ... x + 0)) = y * x`, but sometimes this is something difficult to analyse at once, so read the further explanation.

Now let's see what is changed if we change the x argument to be x + k on example `$result = fun((x + k), y);`

```
$result = 
((x + k) + 1) + ( // fun((x + k), y - 1)        
    (x + k) + ( // fun((x + k), y - 2)  
        .......
                (x + k) + ( // fun((x + k), 1)
                    (x + k) + 0 // fun((x + k), 0) is 0
                )
        .......
    )
);
```

So an important decision is that the change of the argument x, 
doesn't affect on the recursion steps, 
so it will not affect on the solved version of the function.

Now let's change the y argument and analyse the example `$result = fun(x, y + k);`

```
$result = 
x + ( // fun(x, y + k - 1)      
    x + ( // fun(x, y + k - 2)  
        .......
                x + ( // fun(x, (y + k) - k) this is the same as fun(x, y)
                    x + ( // fun(x, y - 1)      
                        x + ( // fun(x, y - 2)  
                            .......
                                    x + ( // fun(x, 1)
                                        x + 0 // fun(x, 0) is 0
                                    )
                            .......
                        )
                    );
        .......
    )
);
```

As we see the change of the argument y also changes the recursion steps

`k = 1, fun(x, (y + 1))` can be solved to `x + fun(x, y)`

`k = 2, fun(x, (y + 2))` can be solved to `x + fun(x, y + 1)` equals to `x + (x + fun(x, y))` equals to `2 * x + fun(x, y)`

So the `fun(x, y)` equals to expression `(y * x)`

Tell me if you want me to continue.